# How to Add the two dropdown ( Normal Dropdown and Google translate) as single /Common Dropdown in Reactjs or HTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

We need that two Dropdown as Single / Common / One  in Reactjs (or) Html …I have attached the Screenshot for your Reference ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ask and need the problem solved, don't forget post source code too so we can see what is wrong with your code :)

Comment: Sorry , we didn't have right to share the code.